# GE Electric Range (model JCB830SF1SS) Burner Not Working

Tags: glass-top-range

I have a GE Electric Range (model JCB830SF1SS) and one of the dual burners turns on, but then shuts off after 30ish secs (**the bigger burner in the image turned off**). I have an image showing the dual burner turned on at max and the smaller burner turned on at the same time. The dual (big) burner shuts off shortly after 30 secs. This happens with and without a pot. I am able to turn it back on, but it turns off after 30 secs. I can hear a click so I'm assuming some sort of safety thing turned it off. Even though it's turned on, it doesn't heat up anymore. So I have to turn it off. Does anyone know if it is the switch or the element that is broken? Or what exactly is the problem/issue?

[image]

Comment: Are you able to turn it back on immediately or does it not work again for a while?

Comment: please show a picture of the control knobs when the double burner is turned on

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I am able to turn it back on, but it turns off after 30 secs. I can hear a click so I'm assuming some sort of safety thing turned it off. Even though it's turned on, it doesn't heat up anymore. So I have to turn it off.

Comment: @jsotola My apologies! I have re-posted the picture

Comment: Have you lifted the top to see if there appears to be any burnt looking wiring or other things that look "wrong".

Comment: @FreeMan I think it is the switch. I don't see anything wrong with the element